# How to re-use a result set produced by executing a sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using `PostgreSQL 8.4`. I need to assign the result set produced by the query to a variable that I can use in another query. For instance, I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    -- some_table_expression
```

I need to use the result of that query in another query like the following:

```
FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(players, 1)
        LOOP
            UPDATE partner.daily_profit 
            SET banner_id = (SELECT banner_id FROM _RESULT_OF_THE_QUERY_ WHERE id = players[i]),
            WHERE partner.daily_profit.player_id = players[i] 
        END LOOP
```

Is there a way to do this in `PostgreSQL 8.4`? I would prefer to not insert the query string as subquery...

Comment: No, you don't need a loop. Just use `WHERE partner.daily_profit.player_id in (select ... )` in your `update` statement and forget about the loop completely. Running DML statements in a loop is almost always the wrong choice.

Comment: In postgres you can use `FROM some_table` in `UPDATE`. With this feature you do not need to `LOOP` over query results. See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-update.html

Comment: If this _was_ a situation where you needed a loop, you'd actually just loop over the query output directly. PL/PgSQL supports that. Or if you needed multiple access / more control, you could create a temporary table.